# Unix find -size -1G ignore files which were returned by find -size -900M?

Tags: linux, unix, find

I need to tar-gzip files below a certain size in a directory. I tried the command suggested from [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/60244/how-to-tar-gz-everything-under-xx-mb) and it works, but when I changed the argument for `find -size` to `-1G`, it ignores some files even when the file size is below 1GB. When I supplied `-100M` and even `-900M` those files were not ignored.

**Some information about the files:**

The files in the directory consists of several medium-sized files (1-200 MB) and thousands of tiny files (<1 MB each).

The medium-sized files are executables (.exe extension).

The tiny files are just some random files with either no extension or .lat extension.

When I supplied `-900M`, all the tiny and medium-sized files are returned as the result. However, when I supplied `-1G`, all the medium-sized files and many tiny files are missing from the result.

**Question:**

Is there anything I miss here about the usage of `-size -1G`?

**Other (possibly useful) info:**

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 as a VM on my Windows 8.1.

If anyone suspects it has something to do with the files I'm working with, please let me know and I will upload the all the files in question.

I'm rather new to Unix/Linux and this is my first question in superuser forum so if I have unintentionally violated any rules please kindly let me know.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50763/find-size-1gb-in-centos. Confirms why your 900MB shows correct results. Try using 1024MB in your query to replace 1G.

Comment: Wow who would have guessed... Thanks @BigChris! Don't you want to post your comment as an answer so I can mark my question as answered?

Answer (score 0):

Answer can be found on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50763/find-size-1gb-in-centos.

In summary, the `-` in `-1G` is like a < sign, so <1G is actually 0G, which is why it does not return files less than 1024M as expected.

I'm still not sure why in my case, it returns some of the tiny files as the result, so if anyone would like to give an explanation for it are welcome to do so.

I'm keeping this question (and answer) because this issue is not unique to CentOS and people searching for the problem without the "CentOS" keyword may not be able to find the post referred above.